# Распознавание текста на отсканированном паспорте Java

Tags: java, поиск-библиотек

Посоветуйте, какие библиотеки использовать, в какую сторону посмотреть?

Comment: В вашем случае смотреть на коммерческие решения, типа DBrain.

Comment: А почему минусы ставят? Вполне хороший вопрос типа "поиск-библиотек"

Comment: @Miron про поиск библиотек в справке написано в разделе "какие вопросы задавать не стоит".

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic раздел "Вопросы по теме, которые тем не менее не стоит задавать", по мне, прежде, чем спрашивать о возможных библиотеках, надо изрыть весь интернет, проделать тщательнейшее исследование и в ЛС поспрашивать всех знакомых в радиусе 2-3 рукопожатий, и только потом уже здесь задавать вопрос. Иначе вопрос не несет пользы для составления базы знаний - того, ради чего SO есть в принципе.

Comment: @mrEvgenX, ну вообще вопрос достаточно конкретный - распознавание паспорта.

Comment: @mrEvgenX, так может я спросил и изрыл весь интернет?

Comment: Может быть... Эти виды вопросов самые неоднозначные. Одни вопросы минусят и закрывают, другие вот так вот поддерживают - видимых отличительных признаков очень мало. В интернете же полно самых разных докладов по обработке изображений... Поэтому не поверю, что такое в такой абстрактной форме можно спрашивать, изрыв весь интернет.

Comment: @mrEvgenX, я нашел кое-что, но в этой области с изображениями я вообще не работал, поэтому захотел узнать еще и мнение людей, задавал вопросы в обычные java паблики, но никто ничего мне не так и не сказал

Comment: Многие компании занимаются этими делами. Ну в моем городе точно есть (не Москва). И они проводят митапы и прочее - смотреть в эту сторону, однозначно. Есть еще сообщество дата-сатанистов OpenDataScience, у них в чатиках чего только ни спрашивают и на что только ни отвечают - вот еще одна сторона.

Comment: @ mrEvgenX Мне просто самому нужно написать, хотел узнать возможно ли такое писать на java, есть ли какие-нибудь готовые решения с открытым исходным кодом или что лучше использовать.

Answer (score 1):

Очень хорошая библиотека компьютерного зрения - OpenCV

Вот демо + есть на канале уроки для старта чайникам: [клик](https://youtu.be/O8HvWdyY_cQ)

Можно сделать распознавание текста с использованием каскадов Хаара: [клик](https://habr.com/ru/post/208092/) и  [еще клик](https://coderoad.ru/6092021/OpenCV-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B4-java-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86)

https://opencv.org/